# Books on the controversy of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, book-recommendation, math-history

I recently finished Amir Alexander’s book Infinitesimal and was looking for similar takes on how complex numbers were accepted into mathematical canon. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I think this question is more fit for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/